# Compatibility mode in excel file when created by Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using POI to create excel file (using HSSFWorkbook) and save with xls file. But when i used higher office (2007+), i got a warning in title bar : Filename.xls [Compatibility Mode].

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

Row row = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(1);

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:/testExcel/workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

How can i configure in in POI to not open file in this mode?

Comment: Have you made sure that you're using the latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: Yes, i used POI 3.10-FINAL

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(myExcelFile);
if (wb instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
    // do whatever
} else if (wb instanceof SXSSFWorkbook) {
    // do whatever
} else if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Your `myExcelFile` can be an `InputStream`, `File`, etc. Check [reference.](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html)

This will allow you to handle .xls and .xlsx extention files. Perhaps your issue can also be handled.